# Filter the /? query parameter at the end of the url

Tags: url, google-analytics

I am reporting in Google Analytics two different pages, one ends in / "homepage" and the other one ends in /? "still homepage". Could someone help me understand why is this happening? does it have to do with the code itself, or something inside GA. I tried to filter and replace but is not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the string **/?** is displayed in Analytics it most likely means that it is sent to Analytics from the site.

Check that you have no querystring in the links that lead to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

There was a filter that needed to be applied: fbclid is the one that it was giving those tailored "?"